# Power BI only returns first pagination when using hash key

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to get data from an API that uses a hash key to get the next page, the key comes from the first request and in order to get the next page I need to append the key and add to the URL like this:

> BASEURL & "&next=" & KEY.

The first page and 2nd page loads fine but when it reaches the 3rd page it keeps giving me the 2nd page **the key does not change based on the page you are in**.

I have run it in postman and I do get the different pages by manually copying and pasting the hash key.

Here is my code:

```
        let

        iterations = 6,          // iterations just for testing

        BaseUrl = Text.Combine({"URL"}),
        Headers0 = [Headers=[header1="header"]],
    
    
        
        GeneratedList =
        List.Generate( ()=>
        [ i= 0, URL = BaseUrl,
        Result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL, Headers0))],
    
    
        each [i]<iterations,
    
        each [ i=[i]+1,
(where "next" is the field of the 1st request that contain the "key" for the next page)
                URL = "URL"&[Result][next],
                Result = Function.InvokeAfter(()=> Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL,Headers0)), #duration(0,0,0,5))
        ]),
```

[This is how my result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3abF1.png)

Comment: I fail to see where you are setting the results of [next]?  Maybe take a look at https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: It's the [Result][next] part of the code "next" is the field that contains the key, I'm using that article already.

Comment: It seems the requests have to be called one after another in some type of session (I'm not sure how that works)

Comment: next" is the field that contains the key -- I understand that part. Where in your code are you setting the value for it?

Comment: It's grabbed from the response, regardless that's not the problem, creating a function and manually inputting the hash key in pbi does not return the 3rd page

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem, if you call the same URL you are going top receive a cached response, my solution was passing a random value in the headers different from the previous call